# apache-camel: http query string parameter as headers?

Tags: http-headers, apache-camel, uri, dsl, query-string

I'm new to camel and prefer using Spring DSL for route definition. Now I find it's confusing, that http query string parameter are named and handled as headers, what they aren't. Is this an architectural bug in camel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Incoming http requests will be added as headers on the exchange with the same name as the query parameter.

Below example is from camel documentation

> For example, given a client request with the URL,
>   http://myserver/myserver?orderid=123, the exchange will contain a
>   header named orderid with the value 123.

You can set the query parameters for other HTTP calls you make by setting by `CamelHttpQuery` header. `Exchange.HTTP_QUERY` is the static constant for string `CamelHttpQuery`

Eg:

```
from("jetty://0.0.0.0:8080/test")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, simple("?param1=${header.param1}")
    .to("http://external-url/test")
```

Comment: don't find it very elegant and it doesn't actually answers my question, but I'm glad that anybody answers and it works:)

Comment: For me, I had to use: simple("param1=${header.param1}", without the question mark.

Comment: without question mark is correct, the doc hasn't it. `.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, constant("order=123&detail=short"))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use toD. For example:

```
from("direct:mycode")
  .toD("https://myurl?param1=${header.param1}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve is use toD component ( SendDynamicProcessor) and internally invoke URL using http4 component.

Use camel-http4 2.X.X. & from Camel 3.X http4 is merged to http.

I'm sharing a way you can generalize and control few things.

1. uri can be dynamically set.
2. Param can be added dynamically when required.
3. You can this route to invoke different endpoints with few config values (headers, body, GET/POST, query params etc).

   ```
   <!-- param will be List or Array of String key=value and make toString to create query of format key1=value1&key2=value2 -->
   <route id="httpInvoker">
      <from uri="direct:httpInvoker"/>
      <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpQuery"><simple>ref:param_bean<simple></setHeader>
      <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpUri"><simple>ref:uri_bean<simple></setHeader>
      <toD uri="http4:\\some-example.com">
   <route>
   ```